Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EmailMessageTemplate' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
I have an issue after I upgrade hibernate in my application from 5.x to 6.x. I am getting the following error

could not execute batch [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ‘EmailMessageTemplate’ when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.]

My application supports 3 databases MySql, SQL Server and Oracle but I am getting the above error only in SQL Server database. Can someone please give a suggestion to resolve this issue?
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EmailMessageTemplate_SeqGenerator",
       sequenceName = "EmailMessageTemplate_Seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator ="EmailMessageTemplate_SeqGenerator")
 private int id;


https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/cannot-persist-a-new-record-due-to-identity-insert-is-set-to-off/95

@DaleK Thanks for quick reply. After I added the following property in hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy in persistence.xml in MySql sequence is not created for each entity but in SQL Server still the sequence is created for each entity is it cause an issue ?
